# MVC4 Linq Query Optimisation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the below code which works  but I do not feel this is the best way to achieve the result.  I am looking at optimising my code.  Any suggestions of a better option will be appreciated. sub  is a subcategory  which is nullable.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult _relatedgrps(string cat, string sub)
    {
         if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sub)){
            var pgs = db.Pages
            .Where(u=>u.MetaNoSearch==false)
            .Where(u => u.PaOk == true && u.Category.Name == cat &&   u.SubCategory.CatName == sub) 
            .OrderByDescending(u => u.PaCreatedOn);
        return PartialView(pgs.ToList());

         }else{
           var pgs = db.Pages
            .Where(u=>u.MetaNoSearch==false)
            .Where(u => u.PaOk == true && u.Category.Name == cat ) 
          .OrderByDescending(u => u.PaCreatedOn);   
        return PartialView(pgs.ToList());

    }}
```

Comment: That formatting is awful to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object to query it. To improve it, you also could remove it boolean comparations because they are conditions.

```
var query = db.Pages.Where(u => !u.MetaNoSearch && u.PaOk && u.Category.Name == cat);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sub))
    query = query.Where(u => u.SubCategory.CatName == sub);

query = query.OrderByDescending(u => u.PaCreatedOn);

return PartialView(query.ToList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Linq IEnumerables can be additive and the query will only be executed when enumerated for the first time (like calling `.ToList()`).  So you should be able to do something like this:

```
var pgs = db.Pages
    .Where(u => u.MetaNoSearch == false &&
           u.PaOk == true &&
           u.Category.Name == cat);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sub))
{
    pgs = pgs.Where(u => u.SubCategory.CatName == sub);
}

return PartialView(pgs.OrderByDescending(u => u.PaCreatedOn).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3021830 - be careful with String.IsNullOrWhitespace, you cannot use that in a database query.  You could do String.IsNullOrWhitespace(sub), but not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(u.*).

I'd avoid any conditionals in the query because that will likely result in a case statement in the SQL.

To produce the best SQL I'd do something like this:

```
var pgs = db.Pages.Where(u => u.MetaNoSearch == false)
                    .Where(u => u.PaOk == true)
                    .Where(u => u.Category.Name == cat);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sub))
{
    pgs = pgs.Where(u => u.SubCategory.CatName == sub);   
}

var result = pgs.OrderByDescending(u => u.PaCreatedOn).ToList();
```

Comment: @Paul Abbott - damn, beat me to it!